# EntityFramework фильтрация

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Использую EF Core
Есть таблицы Product и Catgory - отношение многие ко многим. Промежуточная таблица ProductCategory.
Необходимо получить все продукты принадлежащие одновременно нескольким категориям (с1 && c2 && c3). Пользователь указывает айдишники категорий.
Подскажите как написать запрос

Answer (score 1):

Можно действовать через категории:

```
var prods = context.Categories
                   .Where(c => c.id == c1 || c.id == c2 || c.id == c3)
                   .SelectMany(c => c.Products)
                   .Distinct();
```

Или через продукты:

```
var prods = context.Products
                   .Where(p => p.Categories
                                .Contains(c => c.id == c1 || c.id == c2 || c.id == c3));
```

При необходимости добавьте в нужные места `.Include`, я писал код по памяти, поэтому без него.

Если вы правильно составите модель, то о существовании промежуточной таблицы `ProductCategory` вам вообще ничего знать не нужно. Используйте CodeFirst и будет вам счастье :)